# Giving answers that don't solve the issues but offer a different approach

Tags: discussion, answers

Does it make sense to post anwsers which solve posted problems by offering a completely diferent approach which in essence still solves the problem.

But im talking in the sense, that someone is trying to achieve something in a way that is cleary a bad one, or maybe a deprecated - non future proof, or something similar. And for example, you know how to fix this in the context of his/her current solution, but you also know a different - better way, either through different software, other data formats or whatever. Should you just tell about the quick patch or try to present your approach?

What's your opinion on this?

Comment: It is a good option to have answer from large range of users with background experience.

Answer (score 14):

**I think this is a great approach:** giving someone a good answer to the problem they really have, rather than a good answer to the problem they *think* they have, can make a huge difference both to them and to future readers.

Doing this usually requires an initial dialog, via comments, in which you--the potential respondent--seek to clarify and better understand what the problem really is.  You might also need to ascertain what resources (such as software and conceptual understanding) are available for the solution; for instance, it might not help much to propose a raster-based solution when the O.P. does not have access to raster processing software.

Comment: +1 I would want to learn how to do things correctly if I'm approaching a problem the wrong way.